# Espresso Library Version not compatible with Android Version 23.1.1+

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, android-espresso

The following versions of Espresso libraries are **NOT** compatible with versions above Android 23.1.1:

1. 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
2. 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2'
3. 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2'

Because of this I am unable to use anything above 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1' which is causing this error:[image]

Files imported

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlacePhotoMetadata;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlacePhotoMetadataResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
```

If anyone has a solution to work around this, please help me.

Comment: show your `build.gradle` please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following configuration works:

```
defaultConfig {
    // ...
    testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    //compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1"
    //compile "com.android.support:design:23.1.1"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1" //THIS IS REQUIRED!
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1"

    // Unit Tests
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2"

    // Espresso Idling Resource
    compile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.1"

    // Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1"

    // Espresso UI Testing dependencies.
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1") {
        exclude group: 'javax.inject'
    }
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1") {
        exclude group: 'javax.inject'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1"
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1"
}

configurations.compile.dependencies.each { compileDependency ->
    println "Excluding compile dependency: ${compileDependency.getName()}"
    configurations.androidTestCompile.dependencies.each { androidTestCompileDependency ->
        configurations.androidTestCompile.exclude module: "${compileDependency.getName()}"
    }
}
```

Please try if changing 2.2.1 to 2.2.2 still works.

And now that I glanced at your question again, I think your issue is with the `google play services` version, not the support library version.

Comment: can you tell me the minimum android support version needed to run google play-services-location:9.2.0

Comment: It seems to me that your problem is not the support library, and that you have to add the following dependency `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'`

Comment: I have it added. Still doesn't function

Comment: Excluding the dependencies was the cue.